# Is there an open source F# Tree data structure?

Tags: f#, tree, immutability

I need a simple tree like this, with all the fixings -

```
type 'a Tree =
    | Leaf of 'a
    | Branch of 'a Tree list
```

There's got to be something like this available already with nice add, remove, map, filter, fold functions etc, but I can't find it. I don't even see one from OCaml that I can port... Guess I could write one myself if necessary.

**EDIT: Changed structure of tree to be more obvious.**

Comment: I'm surprised FSharpx doesn't have one.

Comment: Don't know if this is helpful — I've found a basic `Tree<_>` type with `ofSeq` and `toSeq` functions is sufficient most of the time. You can then leverage `map`, `reduce`, etc from the `Seq` module following this basic sequence: `toSeq` > `Seq.(op)` > `ofSeq`. It also makes it easier to change the order of traversal (DFS, BFS) instead of baking it into each function.

Comment: Your tree seems a little odd to me. You can have `Branch(_, [Empty, Empty, Empty, ...])`?

Comment: Ya, I think it's not quite there. But, it's friday and my brain hurts so... as long as I get the point across as to what I want :)

Comment: If you want to share what you're hoping to do, more concrete advice could be offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difficulty is that a simple tree (with say `add Tree Tree`) would be used by no one. Without specifying a more concrete type of tree you would have to implement all of those methods by scanning, tanking performance.

Additionally in place updates of immutable trees are very expensive, since there are few shared data structures in the typical design.

Finally, immutable trees have to be completely rewritten every time if you allow any kind of back tracking.

Comment: Ya, I suppose I would be building my tree from leaves to root, so maybe an add function wouldn't be too useful. Still, I see some good general uses for the data structure when used appropriately.

Comment: @BryanEdds: The problem is there isn't a good middle-ground. If you include a bunch of functions that are useless, then no one will use them, if you don't include the functions, you are no longer delivering any value.